# Python sleep do not work in a Conda Environment in VS Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, conda

I have the following code snippet

```
import time
print("Printed immediately.")
time.sleep(2.4)
print("Printed after 2.4 seconds.")
```

In the VS Code: Conda Environment it does not print statement 01 first and statement 02 after 2.4s delay. Instead both are printed at the same time after 2.4s delay.This issue is not visible in the native python version (Python 3.x with Mac OS). How to resolve this issue?

p.s I found out that this error is related with the executing command. The default command which is executed is

```
conda run -n env_name python "path/test_print.py"
```

if it is changed as follows it prints with the time delay

```
python "path/test_print.py"
```

how to change the default executing command in VS Code?

Comment: "how to change the default executing command in VS Code?" - so is this a completely different question now?

Comment: Not a completely a different question, but its related with the command which is used to execute the file. Either way is there a way to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I think the underlying issue here is that "conda run" buffers stdout until the command completes - see: https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/9412 - but in the mean time I guess the only workaround is to change the executing command. I think the default launch command changed in the most recent (2020.1.57204) VS Code python extension release as I didn't have any such problems before this.

I found that changing the VSCode Python extension setting for condaPath from the default (blank) to something *invalid* - eg condaX - has the effect of changing the launch command from "conda run -n ...", to "& C:/ProgramData/Anaconda3/envs/tf-gpu/python.exe full_path_to_py_file.py" - which has the effect of running in the appropriate conda environment (tf-gpu in my case) without the IO buffering issue. (I'm running on Windows obviously.)

I had previously set up conda launching using https://medium.com/@udiyosovzon/how-to-activate-conda-environment-in-vs-code-ce599497f20d and I'm not sure if any of those changes had any bearing on the issue but I have since reinstalled the VSCode python extension and can find no trace of those changes, so I doubt any of them are necessary for the condaPath change to work as Ive described.

Comment: I can confirm the issue is `conda run` and the solution is to either switch off of Anaconda or wait until the next point release of the Python extension which will be rolling back the `conda run` usage.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you don't use any virtual environment in native python, you can do it by:

1. Open up a terminal in VS Code (or use OS' terminal)
2. Assuming your default python is linked to python2, type `which python3`. You will get something like `/usr/bin/python3`
3. Open VS Code's user settings in the project folder you in. If there is not, create one: `.vscode/settings.json`.
4. Type and save

```
{
    "python.pythonPath": "/usr/bin/python3"
}
```

Or if you want to change it globally, do it in the settings file -> preferences -> settings and search for python path, and make it `/usr/bin/python3`

Comment: This can be simply done using the footer section of the VSCode. Bit the issue here is then I need to install the packages to the default python version. Then that will be conflict with the other programs. As an example for one script i need Tensorflow 1.14 while the other script need Tensorflow 2.0. Previously there was no such issue. As I explained earlier this is related with the way the command is executed. Is there a way to change the executing command?